# content[i] is undefined when push into array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have json data like below

```
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'mobile',
    parentid: 0,
    limit:3
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'samsung',
    parentid: 1
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'moto',
    parentid: 1
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'redmi',
    parentid: 1
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'honor',
    parentid: 1
  }, {
    id: 6,
    name: 'tv',
    parentid: 0,
    limit:3
  }, {
    id: 7,
    name: 'tv1',
    parentid: 6
  }, {
    id: 8,
    name: 'tv2',
    parentid: 6
  }, {
    id: 9,
    name: 'tv3',
    parentid: 6
  }, {
    id: 10,
    name: 'tv4',
    parentid: 6
  }, {
    id: 11,
    name: 'tv5',
    parentid: 6
  }];
```

i took parentid zero from json and made a loop in ng-repeat

```
    $scope.cat = categories.filter(function(category) {
        return category && category.parentId === 0
    });
```

i have created ng-repeat for this category.whgen i click category all corresponding sub categories pushed into array but when i tried to push my data into array i am getting an error

```
$scope.category_modal = function(id)
{
    for(var i =0;i<=$scope.content.length;i++)
    {
        if($scope.content[i].parentId === id && typeof $scope.content[i] != 'undefined')
        {
            $scope.newcat.push($scope.content[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

my view page looks like below

```
<div ng-repeat="item in cat">
{{item.name}}
<button ng-click="category_modal(item.parentid)"></button>
</div>
```

here i got an error as $scope.content[i] is undefined

Comment: your `categories.filter` would return an array with one element. Did you mean to get the object? Maybe you need to add an evaluation `[0]`.

Comment: i am getting 1 and 6 data from json in $scope.cat  array

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting values in $scope.content?
If yes , check have you declared properly

```
$scope.content = [];
```

Comment: yes i got values in $scope.content.if i put console within for loop i got value in $scope.content.if i put console outside for loop it does not display that console

Comment: It may be reference issue , before push in to this.content JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))

Comment: $scope.content.push(JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data))